VSCode Showing commits on left side of editor, how to close
I accidentally hit some combination of CTRL/ALT etc. keys, but I don't know which ones.
This caused VSCode to switch my editor window to a split screen.

On the left hand side it is now displaying commit history associated with each line in the editor. As I select lines, different blocks of test are highlighted (a cobalt background, but your scheme may be different). I'm sure this mode is helpful if you're working on the file history, but that is not the problem working on right now and it's just lost screen real estate and visual noise.
Most importantly, how can I close this pane? Second, how did I open it in the first place?

Are you using GitLens extension?

Regardless, you can identify how you opened the panel by pressing Ctrl+Shift+P (Windows/Linux) or Cmd+Shift+P (Mac) to open the Command Palette. In the list of recently used commands, you can find the one that activated the panel, which will help you understand how it was opened and how to close it properly.

Yes, I have GitLens installed (but I don't use it much.)

@rrcabrera9625 Nice suggestion. In my case, that didn't produce anything in the top recently used commits that I don't recognized or matches the events described.

Why is this getting down votes? I realize that "I'm not sure why my tool did this." is vague, but it's not like I haven't described that problem in enough detail for a knowledgable person to be helpful or ask the necessary follow ups.

If you're using GitLens, you can try disabling the Git blame annotations by pressing Ctrl + Shift + P, typing "GitLens: Toggle Line Blame," and then hitting Enter... hope it helps!

This is a really common behavior that I also accidentally run into. It is really vague like there is no any indicator or feedback to show what triggered it.

I am pretty sure as well that is it related to Gitlens extension as I have it installed too

I think I figured it out and this question seems related to this another Stack Overflow post in some extent. So what you are seeing is the git blame history and you can activate it by going to three horizontal dots on the top right corner, icons by GitLens and there is File Annotations option and the Toggle File Blame is the one responsible for the split screen.
You can remove it with Clear File Annotations option once it is enabled.


Click the Gitlens icon on the top right if you are using the extension.
Gitlens Icon
